# Show code demos online

Tags: jquery, html, css, hosting

Is any website where I could upload my JQuery/Javascript, CSS, and HTML projects to show  demos?

I am looking for any free file hosting service

- to show my demos,
- has a public download location for those files,
- and is more than just storing files on their server.

I have asked this question because I would be providing links on my wordpress.com blog where I can't store files or show their demos.  For example, I create a lightbox with JQuery, now I would like everyone to see its demo.

Comment: no **closers strike** pleaaaaaaaase, this is legitimate question, i would be providing links on my **wordpress.com** blog (where i can't store files or show their demos). Think just a little before clicking that **close** link. Thank you :)

Comment: I have told the legitimate reason but still close continues, this is really bad :(

Comment: Your reason is not programming related. You want to know how to host content on the Internet. That is not a programming question.

Comment: @jmucchiello: It is programming related, who else can tell me other than **programmers** about how do they demo their projects?? So this question is targeted to programmers not a **common internet surfer** who has nothing to do with programming or hosting any projects made in jquery, etc. They are better off uploading images and videos, that's it. Hope that clarifies. Thanks

Comment: Hosting content is hosting content regardless of whether it is a programmer's jQuery widget or my Aunt Martha's pictures of her dogs. If wordpress doesn't let you host files, find webhost who does. You might have to pay for that privilege.

Comment: @jmucchiello: you said "If wordpress doesn't let you host files, find webhost who does. You might have to pay for that privilege". If I had to do this, i would not have asked this question. You consider this not a programming related, i do. There are things everyone takes in different fashion. So, I won't be replying anymore. Thanks

Comment: I'm with Sarfraz, his question is not "what is the cheapest host, or what hosting provider do you use", check the right column, questions about svn providers, Ec2 questions. Why his question is different ? It's not 100% programming related but it helps programmers, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://kodingen.com

Online Development Environment, Code Editor, Cloud Hosting, Database Administration, Collaboration, free hosting etc...

Another great list of editors is [here](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-useful-online-code-editors).

Hope it helps,
Sinan.

Answer (score 5):

If it's quick/lightweight, then http://jsbin.com/

Comment: if i create something there and create a link, will that link be permanent because i will be providing link for it on my blog which means links generated from js bin should be permanent. Are they permanent?

Comment: I've done some pretty involved things on jsbin. It doesn't necessarily have to be lightweight.  Although... I've only done single page demos.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net or 
http://pastebin.me or 
http://jsbin.com

As for link permanence: they're as permanent as any 3rd-party free service is expected to be. In other words, use at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

i think http://jsfiddle.net/ is better than others

Answer (score 1):

I have just figured out that a good way is hosting your source code on a nice provider like GitHub and then use a PaaS in order to build/test and to deploy your application into a runtime environment. On this way, you could show the complete lifecycle: Development+Runtime.